# How do I open a file in python whilst using PyQt5

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

I wish to use a QPushButton to open a file that is contained in the same folder as the program.
This is my code:

```
    file1 = self.lineedit1.text()
    file1 = file1 + ".txt"
    self.button1.clicked.connect(self.open_file(file1))
```

This is my function that is called:

```
    def open_file(clicked, file):
        os.startfile(file)
```

Any idea why it isn't working?
Many Thanks

EDIT: When I run it through IDLE (f5) it opens the file before it even builds the gui meaning I haven't even pressed the button yet and it is calling the function and the program crashes. When I run it by clicking the executable file it crashes instantly without opening the file and building the gui.

Comment: how is it not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Signal-Slot-Connections must be made between a signal and a *callable*. You invoke your open_file-Function immediately, instead of just passing it as callable.

Also, you evaluate the lineedit-text too early - I presume you want to take it's value when the button is clicked, not when the code is run to set things up.

Thus the code looks roughly like this:

```
 # local function closure, thus it knows self
 # from the surrounding
 def open_file():
     file1 = self.lineedit1.text() + ".txt"
     os.startfile(file)

self.button1.clicked.connect(open_file) # no call!
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works now :)
Although I did mean to evaluate it early, its a read only line edit widget, working as a label (only using it for aesthetics tbh) but you wouldn't have known that from my context